# How to check if there is a ceiling above the player?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added crouching to my movement script, what messing is to check if there is a ceiling above the player, and if there is the player should remain crouched. How would I achieve this?

currently, for crouching, the user should press the `c` key and if he wants to stand up, he should press it again.

[image]

UPDATED CODE:

```
if (crouching)
        {
            isRunning = false;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, crouchYScale, transform.localScale.z);
            movement = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
            controller.Move(movement * crouchSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, startYScale, transform.localScale.z);
            movement = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
            controller.Move(movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

 controls.Player.Crouch.performed += _ => OnCrouch();
```

Here is my attempt:

```
public void OnCrouch()
    {

        RaycastHit hit;

       bool checkCeiling =  Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit, 2f);
        if (crouching && checkCeiling == true)
        {
            crouching = false;
        }
        else
        {
            crouching = true;
        }
    }
```

But this does not show any result. the Player still can stand up even if there is a near ceiling above his head. How can I prevent standing up if there is a near ceiling and allow it only when there is enough space to stand up? please help.

Comment: I need more information about your issue. First of all, did you check your `JumpCheck` variable is working as intended (is it detecting the ceiling, i.e., `JumpCheck.collider != null` ?) Second, when you say your `JumpCheck` did not work as expected, what did you expect and what happened instead (e.g., your character stood through the ceiling?) Finally, how exactly did you use your `JumpCheck` variable?

Comment: Ok, I edited my question and added my attempt and result. actually, when I added this check I was not able to crouch whatsoever.

Comment: This is because the code in its current state only let's you crouch if there is a ceiling above the player, which cannot be achieved without being crouched in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Most game logic allows to uncrouch only if there is no ceiling above the player, but does not auto-crouch upon approaching low-ceiling areas. In your toggle function, do the ray cast like this:

```cs
public void OnCrawl()
{
  if(crouching && Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, 2f).collider == null) 
    crouching = false;
  else 
    crouching = true;
}
```

Keep the rest of your code as is and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried this, now the player is crouching and standing up continuously even if I'm not pressing anything.

Comment: This would imply that `OnCrawl` is called continuously, which should not be happening in the first place. Make sure `OnCrawl` is really only called when the crouch action is performed.

Comment: ok so I fixed it being called continuously but using the condition does not change anything. the can still stand up when there is a near ceiling above him.

Comment: Did you make sure that `Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, 2f)` successfully determines whether the player is below a low ceiling? What happens if you `Debug.Log` the raycast result in Update; does it work correctly?

Comment: it prints "Null" everytime the player crouch

Comment: Well, then it seems like the ray cast does not work as intended and this is unrelated to the issue before. Make sure the ceiling has a collider and you can successfully hit it with a ray cast.

Comment: I do have a collider attached to the ceiling, but it is weird that using this condition made the player be able to walk through the ceiling as if there is no collider. anyway, thanks for your help. I will try to figure this out